# Find PID VB.net

Tags: vb.net, process, pid, restart, process.start

I am trying to make a server launcher in my game. I have to launch GameServer.exe with different configs.
GameServer.exe GameServer1.cfg
GameServer.exe GameServer2.cfg
GameServer.exe GameServer3.cfg etc.

Here's the current code I have to start each of those .exe's and .cfg's

```
Private Sub GS1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GS1.Click
    Dim path As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
    Dim gameservercfg As String = GameServer1.Text
    Dim newpath As String = path + ("\")
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newpath + "GameServer.exe ", gameservercfg)
End Sub
```

And here's my code to restart it by process name.

```
Private Sub GSRES_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GSRES.Click
    Dim path As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
    Dim gameservercfg As String = GameServer.Text
    Dim newpath As String = path + ("\")
    Dim p() As Process

    p = Process.GetProcessesByName("GameServer")
    If p.Count > 0 Then
        ' Process is running
        Process.GetProcessesByName("GameServer")(0).Kill()
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newpath + "GameServer.exe ", gameservercfg)
    Else
        ' Process is not running
        MsgBox("GameServer is not running!")
    End If
End Sub
```

With that code, it's restarting random gameservers.
Question is, how do I do that by ProcessID instead of Process name?

Comment: `Process.Start()` returns a `Process` object. Save that (or the `Id` property itself) in a variable or list, and then use that saved process ID to kill the exact process you want with `Process.GetProcessById()`.

Comment: @NateBarbettini I hope you can provide a code for me. I'm pretty new with vb.net.

Comment: There isn't enough information in the question to understand what your exact problem is. Why do you need to restart the process? How is your program supposed to know which one to kill?

Comment: @NateBarbettini you got the idea on your first comment but idk how to code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're after here...but this will kill the existing game instance if it's running before starting it again:

```
Private Games As New Dictionary(Of String, Process)

Private Sub GS1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GS1.Click
    Dim gameservercfg As String = GameServer1.Text
    Dim Key As String = gameservercfg.ToUpper

    If Games.ContainsKey(Key) Then
        If Not Games(Key).HasExited Then
            Games(Key).Kill()
        End If
        Games.Remove(Key)
    End If

    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
    psi.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "GameServer.exe")
    psi.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(psi.FileName)
    psi.Arguments = gameservercfg
    Games.Add(Key, System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi))
End Sub
```

Comment: This code works great, but I want this code in a separate button just for restarting. And when button click if that specific gs is not running then it will ask for the user to run it first. @Idle_Mind